An approximation of real numbers with a given irrational
Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number and $\theta$ is an arbitrary real number. For any positive number $\delta$, are there positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $|\theta -m\alpha -n|\leq \delta ?$
For the above sentence to be true, I guess one should use somehow the "denseness" of the irrational numbers in the set of real number and approximate $\theta$ with a linear combination as above. Can anybody be so kind as to help me?

The way this is stated, it's not true.  If $\theta < -1$ and $\alpha > 1$, then $\theta - m\alpha - n < -3$, so the $|\cdot | > 3$.  I think it's true if $n$ can be chosen to be any integer.

FYI, see this answer (found using an Approach0 search).

Yes: when $\alpha$ is irrational, the fractional parts $\{m\alpha\} = m\alpha - \lfloor m\alpha\rfloor$ are dense in $[0,1)$, so in particular will come within $\delta$ of $\{\theta\}$ which gives what we want.
Keywords for further exploration are “inhomogeneous Diophantine approximation”.

However, OP's statement is not true when both $m$ and $n$ are restricted to positive integers and $\theta < -1$.
